# Complementary Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I know that for a 2nd order linear ODE, the complementary function is a general linear combination of two linearly independent solutions of the corresponding homogeneous equation. (Hopefully I'm not too far off from the actual definition.) This can easily be  generalized to higher orders.
In case of a PDE, what's the complementary function and how is it analogous to that of an ODE?

Comment: So how is the complementary function defined for PDEs?

Comment: When we say "solve" do we mean a general solution or a complete solution? (New to the concept. Apologies for ignorance.)

Comment: Cf [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2433327/418542)

Comment: @HritRoy it means general solution.Yet complete solution is another form of general solution